# React Video synthetic events

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue where my Projection Component is updating redux on `onLoadedMetadata` to set the duration and then updating the time `onTimeUpdate` in order to create my own progress bar. I'm having an issue however with `onTimeUpdate` returning values larger than the duration given `onLoadedMetadata`

```
function Projection({ dispatch, video }) {
  return (
    <video
      className={`projectVideo ${ENV}`}
      onTimeUpdate={e => dispatch(videoUpdateAction(e.timeStamp))}
      onLoadedMetadata={e => dispatch(videoLoadedAction(e.currentTarget.duration * 1000))}
      onEnded={() => dispatch(videoEndedAction())}
      autoPlay
    >
      <source src={`/videos/${video}`} type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `e.timeStamp`? From MDN: `In newer implementations, the value is a DOMHighResTimeStamp representing the number of seconds (in milliseconds, accurate to 5 microseconds) since the event was created. `

Comment: when I use `e.DOMHighResTimeStamp` I get undefined.

Comment: `e.timeStamp` uses `DOMHighResTimeStamp` under the hood.  I'm referencing the rest of the sentence, which is that the `timeStamp` property represents the time since the event was created which is probably not what you want.

Comment: You're right! Thank you!